# Encountering issues with Firebase documentation for the GoogleSignIn Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I apologise if my formatting is incorrect, this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I'm bound to make a few mistakes.

I've followed the documentation closely for the GoogleSignIn method of credential authentication, within Firebase. I program in Objective-C, so I've followed the corresponding code for this programming language, within their website's documentation section. Initially, the code did not work at all, requiring me to implement some additional code. For this reason, there will be a few additions to the original documentation, which is implemented within the accompanying code for this post. My issue is that upon login, the user's credentials aren't actually passed to the next class. Instead, it either retains the values of a previous user who logged in using the email authentication method or simply returns no value for the user at all. Sometimes, the newly registered google account shows in the Firebase users section of my applications management area, however, mostly, the accounts don't appear. Is anyone available to help read my code, in the attempt to diagnose my issues? We can assume that my AppDelegate functions and methods have been implemented correctly.

To be clear, I need help understanding why my Google user credentials aren't being passed to the class that is instantiated after the Google Login class. Also, I need help understanding why the user simply has to click the Google sign in button, after the first time entering their account details, and they're automatically logged in without any prompts.

The code for the class that contains the Google login, and the class that comes after the google login, where the credentials are required:

Google Login Class:

```
#import "GoogleLogin.h"
@import Firebase;
@import GoogleSignIn;

@interface GoogleLogin ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *googleLoginButton;

@end

@implementation GoogleLogin

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]; //Added to check if it makes a difference, it doesn't...
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!error)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAccountArea" sender:self];
    }
}
```

MyAccount Class (Only the relevant code):

```
@implementation MyAccount

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    self.usr = [[UserModel alloc]init];

    FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser; //User is either nothing or contains the email address of a user that logs in using an email-based account...
    if (user != nil)
    {
        _emailAddressEntry.text = user.email;
    }

    if ([self.usr getDataForUser:user.email]) 
    {
        [self getUserInfoForDisplay]; //Therefore, this code returns an array with 0 elements, causing the application to crash...
    };
}
```

Comment: Why are you using GoogleSignIn?  Firebase?  Firebase what?  There are several Firebase products, which involve Firebase Auth, not GoogleSignIn.

Comment: Ok, so I need to provide some background information/context. I'm developing an iOS Application that requires 2 methods of credential authentication. The ones I've chosen are the, standard, email login and google login methods of credential authentication. For this application, to satisfy the google login requirement, I've implemented the google login authentication method (Which, to my understanding, both registers and logs in the user). My present issue is that the functionality is not the same as what is desired/expected.

Comment: Within the documentation for an iOS Application, I'm implementing the provided documentation for the Google Sign-in authentication method, underneath the enclosing "Authentication" section.

Comment: user simply has to click the Google sign in button, after the first time entering their account details, and they're automatically logged in without any prompts because it is saving authtoken, and it is normal behaviour, if you want user has to enter credentials on every time them simply destroy this token or use logout function.

Comment: Even when the logout function is used, the same behaviour persists. Moreso, I want to know why the credentials aren't being shown underneath the currentUser.

Comment: Okay.  You are right.  I forgot.  So you use the Google Sigin method.  That's why you are using GoogleSignIn.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/login-demo-ios/tree/master/Login%20Demo

Comment: "why my Google user credentials aren't being passed to the class that is instantiated after the Google Login class"  To which class?  Provided that you are talking about MyAccount, I don't see any connection between GoogleLogin and MyAccount.  Secondly, those classes names misleading.  If they are view controllers, you should name them after 'viewController.'  And I don't know wny FireAuth comes into play in MyAccount.

Comment: I've renamed these View Controllers to these names, after receiving advice that leaving them with "VC" or "View Controller" in the names makes it messier and harder to navigate through my files. Similarly to how my Email Login class functions, "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAccountScreen" sender:self];", I am passing all values for the data held by variables in the class, as I transition to the next view controller. This should pass the aforementioned data, such as the user's ID.

Comment: Also, @SachinVas, I don't think that code is up to date. For one, "Firebase" is not an object, anywhere... So it's impossible for his code to actually work. At least, with the imports he has.

Comment: To clarify, the connection between GoogleLogin and MyAccount is the transitioning between them through the use of a segue. This process is identical to how I achieve this through the EmailLogin View Controller. However, the EmailLogin View Controller contains zero bugs or issues, whereas this View Controller fails to identify the currentUser. Which, I'm experimenting to solve through the use of the github link posted by another user, above.

Comment: So, I've resolved one issue, by resetting currentUser everytime the user logs out. Thank you @aBilal17. However, I now need help tackling the bigger issue, which is why the google login isn't actually showing any new user's in firebase, but still letting the user login and not returning any errors or issues until we need to identify who the current user is.